# Importing dataset to R with variable titles in every observation

Tags: r, dataset

```
    Example:
    [{"Variablename1":1,"Variablename2":yes,"Variablename3":[{"subvariablenamel":1,
"subvariablename2":null},
{"subvariablenamel":2,"subvariablename2":null}]},"Variablename1":3,
"Variablename2":no,"Variablename3":[{"subvariablenamel":2,"subvariablename2":null},
{"subvariablenamel":1,"subvariablename2":null}]}]
```

The 3rd variable seems particularly complicated to import. It would also be fine if i could somehow read the dataset without that variable. I would like to use read.table, but any method will suffice. The variables with the observation "null" is just a factor that can only be "null" for any observation (its a placeholder you could say).

The dataset: (i should be able to import it if i can just get help with importing the example, so not necessary to look at)
http://hotsapi.net/api/v1/replays?min_id=1&start_date=2018-03-20&end_date=2018-03-29&game_type=HeroLeague&with_players=false

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON format file. NOTE: Your example doesn't quite follow JSON syntax - strings must be quoted such as "yes" and "no"

```
library(jsonlite)

text <- readLines("http://hotsapi.net/api/v1/replays?min_id=1&start_date=2018-03-20&end_date=2018-03-29&game_type=HeroLeague&with_players=false")
my_list <- fromJSON(text)
```